# Inserting captions under photographs in word based on entries in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, performance, memory-management, ms-word

I have a macro written in word for transferring captions written in excel to a corresponding photograph in a word document. At the moment it runs however I am finding that it slows down over time the more captions it has to process. As such it is useful for up to approximately 200 photographs however I need it to process 1000+. I believe that it is because I am referencing the excel workbook rather than transferring the data into an array however I have not been able to successfully achieve transferring the excel data into an array. Any help would be much appreciated thank you!

````
sub Cybernet2()
'Add excel object library tools>References

Dim intCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim path As String
Dim oex As Object
Dim exWb As Object
Dim ws As Object
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim rngsort As Excel.Range
Dim rw As Word.Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim xPic As InlineShape

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Set oex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oex.Visible = False
path = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(2).Range.Text
Set exWb = oex.workbooks.Open(path, , True)
Set ws = exWb.Worksheets(1)
'lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'Set rngsort = ws.Range(Cells(1, "b"), Cells(lr, "b"))
Set doc = ActiveDocument

For i = doc.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1

Set rw = doc.InlineShapes(i).Range
doc.InlineShapes(i).Select
Selection.InsertCaption "Photograph", ":" & ws.Cells(i, "b").Value, "", wdCaptionPositionBelow, 0

Next i

End Sub ```
````

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/148668-post5.html